# Ошибка: Использование не определённого класса. (С++)

Tags: c++

Предположим я имею... класс "`А`" и метод "`print`" с входящим параметром экземпляра класса "`B`"

```
class A { void print(B value){} };

class B {};
```

Есть ли возможность скомпилировать данный код хоть каким-нибудь инструментом в С++?
А также учитывайте тот факт, что просто переставить классы местами возможности не представляется,
данная ошибка программы представлена в виде примера, в действительности же классов много и код большой, но сущность ошибки не меняется.

Я также пробовал объявить класс "`B`"... не помогло :(

```
class B;
class A { void print(B value){} };

class B {};
```

Буду рад любой помощи... спс.

Comment: *"просто переставить классы местами возможности не представляется"* - предоставленный пример этого не отражает, а сам вопрос по ходу является проблемой XY и вместо этого стоило спросить про то, почему не получается переставить классы.

Comment: Мима......... )

Comment: _"просто переставить классы местами возможности не представляется"_ - представленный пример и не должен этого отображать. Так как, во первых, я к этому не стремился, а во вторых мне известно почему их нельзя переставить местами.
А что именно является проблемой, думаю мне лучше знать так-как код передо мной, а не перед вами. Нет, проблема не в _XY_.
Лучше бы спросили у меня, чем подставлять факты под свою теорию )

Comment: *"код передо мной, а не перед вами"* - тут обсуждается только тот код, который представлен в вопросе, а не какой-то другой, который кроме вас никто не видел. Отсутствие обсуждаемого кода в вопросе переводит его в категорию офтопика с последующим закрытием. И все заявления вида *"переставить классы местами возможности не представляется"* необходимо подкреплять, приводя [mcve]

Comment: Ваши первые комментарии не уместны, всё последующее ваши слова только добавляет хаоса.
Повторяю...
Представленный пример и не должен отображать все ваши замечания! Он отображает только ту суть, которую я стремился выяснить, и только ту проблему, которую я хотел решить! И проблема решена!
Остальной код, как по моему мнению, не уместно добавлять, так как она не участвует в ошибке, и только лишний раз грузит того, кто хотел бы мне помочь.
Я старался максимально упростить код для чтения и восприятия, и стремился к тому чтобы чтец уловил сому суть проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте ссылку/адрес:

```
class B;
class A { void print(const B& value){} }; // или print(const B* value)
class B {};
```

Так, как вы написали — без *полного* знания класса `B` компилятор обойтись не в состоянии...

Comment: Так заморачиваться ни к чему, достаточно переставить определение классов местами.

Comment: @user7860670 У ТС вопрос по сути не для конкретного пустого класса, а почему не работает предварительное объявление. В общем случае "переставить местами" решением не является...